# How to operate with json list in CMake?

Tags: json, cmake

I have the following code which I'm trying to read in CMake.

```
   {
    "demo": [
     {
      "name": "foo0",
      "url": "url1",
      "verify_ssl": true
     },
     {
      "name": "foo1",
      "url": "url1",
      "verify_ssl": true
     },
     {
      "name": "foo2",
      "url": "url2",
      "verify_ssl": true
     }
    ]
   }
```

I'm trying to access a member from the list above, for example demo[0].name without success, what I'm doing wrong?

```
file(READ "${CONAN_CACHE}/demo.json" MY_JSON_STRING)
string(JSON CUR_NAME GET ${MY_JSON_STRING} demo[0].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

One at a time.

```
string(JSON CUR_NAME GET ${MY_JSON_STRING} demo 0 name)
```